# Steam Family View won't allow Origin games

Tags: steam, origin

If I am on Family View in Steam, games like Madden and Fifa won't start, because they use Origin, and I get an error which says "Error, relaunch your game to continue linking your accounts".
I have also tried launching from Origin, but I get the same thing.
If I turn off Family View, it works fine. Is their a permission I can edit to fix this?

Edit:  Just so it's clear, I'm talking about family *view* not family *sharing*.   The two are easily confused, so I just wanted to make that clear.  =)

Comment: Do you own Madden and Fifa on Origin yourself, and if so, on what platform(s)? Since it's third-party software, additional playability possibilities can't be controlled by Steam.

Comment: I bought it on steam, but since they are origin games they require origin.  I am on pc.  I am just trying to figure out why family mode is keeping the accounts from linking, and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you launch these games through origin?

Comment: I tried that but I got the same error, @Regnegade

Comment: By family mode do you mean this? [link](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5149-eopc-9918)

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.  I edited the question to replace family mode with family view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some games that use 3rd Party DRM features like Origin, Ubisoft Connect (previously uPlay), Rockstar Games Launcher, etc can't be used via Family Mode or Family Sharing.

Sadly the only solution is to disable Family Mode to use this set of games.

Comment: It seems like Ubisoft DRM games do work with family view. At least that is true for Rayman Legends.

Comment: It's getting even weirder: unravel two, which has worked fine in family view just stopped working with family view enabled after a recent update.